# Compile a document as "draft" for the first few times and then non-draft in the final round

Tags: compiling, latexmk

I'm working on a big document in which there are many images.

Usually, I compile it with latexmk and it works quite well. But: with all these images it's quite slow when compiling.

Is it somehow possible to compile it as a draft for the first few rounds and then as a non-draft, so the images are ignored the first few times and properly included in the last round, without editing the file inbetween?

That would save quite a lot of time.

Comment: arara should be the right tool for this, right @PauloCereda?

Comment: Have you tried the `draft` option to `\includegraphics`?

Comment: I don't see how the `\includegraphics`-`draft` would help me here. Before compiling the last time, I'd need to remove that code parts again. My idea is to run everything in draft-mode except for the last run or so. And I have never heard of arara, how would that help me here? thanks.

Comment: @PerikOnti `draft` may change several aspects of the typesetting, depending on which packages you load, so just the final run without it may not be sufficient. The `draft` option should be only to `graphicx`. It's an interesting question anyway.

Comment: do you mean you are running latex multiple times after each edit? if so why? If you are editing between latex runs why is adding/removing `[draft]` a problem?

Comment: @PerikOnti On the other hand, `latexmk` can't know which one is the last LaTeX run, so you need two calls of `latexmk` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `latexmk` can't know which LaTeX run will be the last, so you will need to run it twice.

The first time call it like

```bsh
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex %O '\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}\input{%S}'" <filename>
```

and the second time just with

```
latexmk -pdf -g <filename>
```

In the document you'll just have `\usepackage{graphicx}`. In my test, just one run is performed with the second command.